# Rails 4: Dot in URL to separate IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I use the following line to create a link

```
link_to_remote 'Delete', :url => mail_path(user_id, mail.id), :confirm => 'Delete?', :method => :delete
```

This will create a DELETE request in the form of /mail/4.3 
The route is

```
delete 'mail/:user_id/:id', to: 'mail#destroy'
```

I'm trying to access the two IDs in my controller with

```
@mail = Mail.find(params[:id])
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

However, it fails with error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/mail/4.3")
```

What am I missing here?

Update 1) Output of "rake routes"

```
Prefix     Verb      URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
mail       DELETE    /mail/:user_id/:id(.:format)        mail#destroy
```

Comment: Post the output of `rake routes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is producing the url `/mail/4.3` is because `mail_path` only takes one parameter, so it takes the second as a format. This is because the `mail_path` url helper that you're using isn't for the `DELETE` route that you've posted in your question, but some other route.

The Rails Way would be to have nested resources for `mail` and `user` like:

```
resources :users do
  resources :mail
end
```

Giving you the route helper `user_mail_path(@user, @mail)` (or something similar depending on pluralisation of mail) and the URL `/users/4/mail/3`.

Alternatively, to continue on your path you'll probably have to name your delete route:

```
delete 'mail/:user_id/:id', to: 'mail#destroy', as: 'delete_mail'
```

and use `delete_mail_path(user_id, mail.id)` in your link.